# Java: Building an array of Point2D.Double

Tags: java, arrays

In a constructor I am trying to build an array of Point2D.Double from an Point2D array.
Basically I want to add coordinates to a graph.
I did this:

```
private Point2D.Double [] points;

public EmbeddedGraph(Point2D[] pointArray){
    super(pointArray.length);
    for (int i=0; i<pointArray.length; i++){
    points[i] = new Point2D.Double();
    points[i].setLocation(pointArray[i].getX(), pointArray[i].getY());
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException.

The array of coordinates (pointArray) comes from the given code of the exercise. So I'm guessing the error is on my part.

```
Point2D[] coordinates = new Point2D[4];
coordinates[0] = new Point2D.Double(-14,0);
coordinates[1] = new Point2D.Double(0,10);
coordinates[2] = new Point2D.Double(0,-10);
coordinates[3] = new Point2D.Double(14,0);
EmbeddedGraph g = new EmbeddedGraph( coordinates );
```

Comment: You probably have a null in the array that you're passing in to this constructor.  Can you show us the code where you're creating the `EmbeddedGraph`?

Comment: added to initial question

Comment: OK, now which line throws the Null Pointer Exception?  Your stack trace will tell you this.

Comment: I think I've just got it. I didn't say which size the new array should have. It works for now.

Comment: But can you tell me how I can do a stack trace? This is new to me.

Comment: Yeah, I've just read Samurai Girl's (correct) answer.  Don't know how I missed this!

Comment: The stack trace is the big long error message that starts with "Null Pointer Exception".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to fill `points[]` array when it is null. 
You should do this first:

```
`points = new Point2D[pointArray.length]`
```

(in case it is not done in `super()`);